# JQ agglomerate and count occurrences of a key

Tags: python, jq

I have the following json answer tree from an API:

```
    {links,
        {first: "data_f"
         last: "data_l",
         next: "data_n"
         previous: "data_p"
         self: "data_s"
         }
    {meta
        {itemCount,
         pageCount,
         pageSize,
         }
    waves
        [{
            assets
                [{
                    assetId,
                    changeId,
                    executions,
                        [{
                            added,
                                {isClient,
                                 reason,
                                 userId,
                                 userName,
                                 when,
                                }
                            canceled,
                                {isClient
                                 reason
                                 userId
                                 userName
                                 when
                                }
                            componentId,
                            execId,
                            incidentId,
                            isRemovable,
                            lastEditTime,
                            operationName,
                            operationStatus,
                                {assetNameInBackend,
                                details,
                                elapsedTime,
                                error,
                                firstSentTime,
                                jobId,
                                parentJobId,
                                startTime,
                                state,
                            parentId}
                        }]
                    monitoringBlackout,
                }]
        }]
```

Where waves is a list of processes involving the ***assetsId*** in each wave.

Each ***assetId*** has a list of executions, this is an example of an assetID register:

```
{'assetId': 'myhostname',
  'changeId': 'XXXX',
  'executions': [{'added': {'isClient': True,
     'reason': "random, test",
     'userId': 'xxxx',
     'userName': 'xxxxxx',
     'when': '2022-06-14T12:08:15.820000+00:00'},
    'canceled': None,
    'componentId': 'LINUX_myhostname',
    'execId': 'd618b7f1-c3be-4845-b5e0-432fb6d4efaa',
    'incidentId': None,
    'isRemovable': False,
    'lastEditTime': '2022-06-15T00:08:15.461000+00:00',
    'operationName': 'Pre Check Linux OS 5 business days',
    'operationStatus': {'assetNameInBackend': 'myhostname',
     'details': 'PreCheck OS completed successfully with message: All tests ran successfully',
     'elapsedTime': '0:01:58',
     'error': None,
     'firstSentTime': '2022-06-15T00:03:26.232000+00:00',
     'jobId': 'd80d5863-b96b-45d5-ae9c-3299bb048cf7',
     'parentJobId': '475417ad-72fe-4590-ad3b-afd28286f49a',
     'startTime:': '2022-06-15T00:03:25.657000+00:00',
     'state': 'SUCCESS'},
    'parentId': '6f621a59-3dd0-458c-a3f3-f45af82c6924'},
   {'added': {'isClient': True,
     'reason': "random text",
     'userId': 'x',
     'userName': 'xxxx',
     'when': '2022-06-14T12:08:15.820000+00:00'},
    'canceled': None,
    'componentId': 'LINUX_myhostname',
    'execId': 'e30fe6f0-67d5-4284-bd2b-460afcd05cf6',
    'incidentId': None,
    'isRemovable': False,
    'lastEditTime': '2022-06-21T19:06:44.300000+00:00',
    'operationName': 'Pre Check Linux OS on same day',
    'operationStatus': {'assetNameInBackend': 'myhostname',
     'details': 'PreCheck OS completed successfully with message: All tests ran successfully',
     'elapsedTime': '0:02:37',
     'error': None,
     'firstSentTime': '2022-06-21T19:01:24.388000+00:00',
     'jobId': '9a9b3a39-dca3-445a-a4a5-0a8be8c1c30c',
     'parentJobId': '672141bc-317f-443d-841a-7498e154f4d0',
     'startTime:': '2022-06-21T19:01:23.145000+00:00',
     'state': 'SUCCESS'},
    'parentId': '6f621a59-3dd0-458c-a3f3-f45af82c6924'},
   {'added': {'isClient': True,
     'reason': "random text",
     'userId': 'x',
     'userName': 'x',
     'when': '2022-06-14T12:08:15.820000+00:00'},
    'canceled': None,
    'componentId': 'LINUX_myhostname',
    'execId': '6f621a59-3dd0-458c-a3f3-f45af82c6924',
    'incidentId': 'XXXX',
    'isRemovable': True,
    'lastEditTime': '2022-06-22T00:06:31.429000+00:00',
    'operationName': 'Patch Linux OS',
    'operationStatus': {'assetNameInBackend': 'myhostname',
     'details': 'Error details,
     'elapsedTime': '0:00:33',
     'error': 'ERROR TYPE',
     'firstSentTime': '2022-06-22T00:01:42.387000+00:00',
     'jobId': 'ff3ab5e5-3797-4691-8e91-744d7350a371',
     'parentJobId': 'fd170914-09a7-453a-9e9e-6815f89a30d4',
     'startTime:': '2022-06-22T00:01:57+00:00',
     'state': 'FAILED'},
    'parentId': None}],
  'monitoringBlackout': {'endTime': '2022-06-22T06:01:27.111000+00:00',
   'id': '4137751',
   'message': 'message string',
   'startTime': '2022-06-22T00:01:27.111000+00:00',
   'state': 'REMOVE_FAIL'}}]
```

I'm trying to find the assets that failed (`.executions[].operationStatus.state != "SUCCESS"`), for each wave and identify those that are recurrent for the same reason on the same operation, meaning that failed more than once.

I would like to have an output like:

```
{ assetId: myhostname,
  error: 'NET_ERROR',
  operationName: 'Patch Linux OS'
  failure_count: 'n'
}
```

I've being trying to figure out the way to do it but I don't have the experience with JQ to get the result, this is what I have achieve for the moment:

```
jq.compile('.waves[].assets| map(\
                 select(\
                     (.executions[].componentId | contains("LINUX")) and \
                     (.executions[].operationStatus.state != "SUCCESS") \
                     )\
                 ) | select(length > 0) |  map({"assetId": .assetId, \
                                                "operationName": .executions[].operationName, \
                                                "state": .executions[].operationStatus.state, \
                                                "details": .executions[].operationStatus.details, \
                                                "conponentId": .executions[].componentId, \
                                                "error": .executions[].operationStatus.error})\
                 | map(\
                 select(\
                     (.state != "SUCCESS") \
                     )\
                 ) | group_by(.assetId) | unique').input(job_resp).all()
```

but it's not filtering out the **SUCCESS** state for each operation, any ideas on how to get that output?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
.waves[].assets[]
| .assetId as $assetId
| .executions
| map(select(.operationStatus.state != "SUCCESS"))
| map({ $assetId, error: .operationStatus.error, operationName })
| group_by(.)
| .[]
| first + { failure_count: length }
| select(.failure_count > 1)
```

(Note that `map(…) | map(…)` is the same as `map(… | …)`, but I compromised for readability)

Breakdown:

1. Remember `assetId` in variable
2. Only select those operations with a state different from "SUCCESS"
3. Map to a reduced object containing only your required properties
4. Group identical properties and produce all items from array
5. Add `failure_count` property to the reduced object (only take first from the groups, discard the rest)
6. Select those with more than 1 failure